# How can you gather and deliver data at specific index in an array in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I have this for my custom view:

```
var menu = pickerMenu(frame: view.frame, menuItems: *NSArray here*, andDelegate: self)`
```

What I want to pass to `menuItems:` is all the calendar titles from:

```
var calendarsArray: [EKCalendar] = eStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeReminder) as [EKCalendar]
```

Since naturally users can add and remove calendars and numbers can change I cannot do:

```
    var items = [
        MenuItem (text: calendarsArray[0].title),
        MenuItem (text: calendarsArray[1].title),
        MenuItem (text: calendarsArray[2].title),
        ...
    ]
```

How do I programmatically obtain all the `title` from `calendarsArray` and pass them to `menuItems:`?

I have loop but have no idea how to pass the result to `menuItems`.

```
    for (var i:Int=0; i<calendarsArray.count; i++) {
        //            calendarsArray[i].title;
        println("Title:\(calendarsArray[i].title)")
    }
```

Comment: You can either iterate over the `calendarsArray`, adding each title to the `items` array or you can invoke `valueForKey:@"title"` on the calendars array (assuming `calendarsArray` is actually an NSArray under the covers)

Comment: iterate? Do you mean loop...? I edited the post addded loop I have. However I have no idea how to pass it to outside of the loop itself...

Comment: You would just declare `menuItems` as an array outside the loop `var items = [String]()` and then call `items.append(calendarsArray[i].title)` inside the loop, but the closure version using `map` from the answer below will work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let items = calendarsArray.map { MenuItem(text: $0.title) }
```

should get you an array of `MenuItem`s for every entry in the `calendarsArray`.  Then just pass that into `pickerMenu`.

Comment: Actually I once thought this was something to do `map` when it comes to swift but had no idea what to do with it. Thanks for share!